# I had a gas leak and put a new hose on it. It was fine until we put clamps on and now it's leaking again

Tags: fuel-system, leak, buick, regal

I have a 1996 Buick Regal and I had to replace the hose. I had a gas leak and now that I put clamps around it the gas has started leaking again.

Comment: Any chance you could add some photos of the problem area? My first thought is that the hose clamps are too far down the hose (away from the hose fitting) and aren't clamping on the fitting. Instead they are opening up the hose by squeezing on just hose. If the clamp is more than 1/8 - 1/4 of an inch (3 to 6 mm) from the end of the hose, try moving it closer.

Comment: Fuel injection?    What type of clamps are being used?  What type fuel line?  There are at least five different type of fuel hose clamps, new ones should be used and matched to line type and OEM type.  Fuel line has several types and they should not be interchanged.

Comment: Umm, WHICH fuel hose are you refering to? There's a few on modern engines.

Comment: Fuel leaks, especially on a gasoline engine, are nothing to mess with - too much chance of a fire. No argument against doing the work your self, just be sure you've got it fixed and ideally understand why it leaked and how the fix works.

Comment: That car has a high pressure fuel system, conventional repairs with hose and clamps may not work.